# Get string between last "slash" and first "interrogation mark"

Tags: javascript

I have a url, like this:

```
http://google.com/foo/querty?act=potato
http://google.com/foo/querty/?act=potato
http://google.com/foo/querty/#/21312ads
http://google.com/foo/querty#/1230982130asd
```

How can i get only the "querty" string by using regex in javascript for this format of URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match URLs with "?":

```
str.match(/^.*\/([^\/]+)\/?\?.*$/)[1];
```

To match URLs with "#":

```
str.match(/^.*\/([^\/]+)\/?#.*$/)[1];
```

to match both:

```
str.match(/^.*\/([^\/]+)\/?[#\?].*$/)[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, i've edited my question with a new information. Unfortunately, if i use a `www.foo.bar/123#/abc` the regular expression takes the `abc`. How add the (#) to the regex?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to enter the new question. I need the regex check the # too... like: `www.google.com.br/foo/#/bar` i want the regex to take only the `foo` cause `bar` isn't a "true directory".

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
var url = "http://google.com/foo/querty?act=potato".split('/').pop(),
    urlPart = url.slice(0,url.indexOf('?'));
    console.log(urlPart);
```

I'd strongly suggest *not* using regular expressions for this, given the needless complexity (but that is, of course, a personal preference).

Edited to address the failure of the above to meet both test-cases shown in the question (it fails in the second case). The following handles both cases specified:

```
Object.prototype.lastStringBefore = function (char, delim) {
    if (!char) {
        return this;
    }
    else {
        delim = delim || '/';
        var str = this,
            index = str.indexOf(char),
            part = str.charAt(index - 1) == delim ? str.split(delim).slice(-2, -1) : str.split(delim).pop();
        return part.length === 1 ? part[0] : part.slice(0, part.indexOf(char));
    }
}

var url1 = 'http://google.com/foo/querty?act=potato',
    url2 = 'http://google.com/foo/querty/?act=potato',
    lastWord1 = url1.lastStringBefore('?', '/'),
    lastWord2 = url2.lastStringBefore('?', '/');

console.log(lastWord1, lastWord2);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hNdEq/1/).

References:

- [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: You're right, of course; *edited* to correct that short-coming. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

Use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) to find the `?` and [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to extract part of your string:

```
url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('?'));
```